# less rounded in a calculation

Tags: javascript, acrobat

in a PDF document I have a calculation where the result must be rounded to the nearest whole. the calculation is as follows.
= (Date 1 - Date 2) / 365

exemple : (Date 1 - Date 2) / 365 = 5.67 I would like to round lower whole or 5

Can be in Java Script
Is anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance

Comment: `var a = 5.67 ;`
`console.log(a.toFixed(0));`

Comment: @KinshukLahiri "_...  to round lower whole of 5 ..._".

Comment: Do you mean round to the next lowest 5, as in the number 9.6 would round to 5, the number 11 would round to 10, and the number 2.25 would round to 0?

Comment: Sur l'entier inférieur. Par exemple 6 = 6,85, 7,20 = 7, 11 = 11,43

Comment: `Math.floor()` will round down.

Comment: this style? var date1 = this.getField("dateembauche").value;  
var date2 = this.getField("dateanciennete").value; 

event.value = Math.floor((date1 – date2)/365);

Answer (score 0):

to get to do what I wanted I used the following code. May be a complicated but it works. Thank you for your help

```
var date1 = this.getField("dateanciennete").value;
var date2 = this.getField("dateembauche").value;
if(date1.length && date2.length)
{
  var dateStart = util.scand("mmm d, yyyy",date1);
  var dateEnd = util.scand("mmm d, yyyy",date2);
  var diff = dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime();
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var days = Math.floor(diff/oneDay);
   event.value = Math.floor(days/365);
 }
 else
   event.value = 0;
```